# Connecting to multiple OpenSSL connections

Tags: bash, shell-script, openssl, https

I am trying to make multiple TLS connections from a computer in order to measure some network statistics. I have a file with 1000 domain names. However, when I try to run the following script, the script ends after a while.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
SSLKEYLOGFILE=/home/test/FINALDEMO/keylog.txt LD_PRELOAD=./libsslkeylog.so openssl s_client -connect $line:443 &    done < topsites.txt
```

To get the file, topsites.txt. Run

```
curl -s -O http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip ; unzip -q -o top-1m.csv.zip top-1m.csv ; head -1000 top-1m.csv | cut -d, -f2 | cut -d/ -f1 > topsites.txt
```

Can someone please help me understand how do I verify the number of websites I have connected too and how to send any kind of application data after connecting with openssl client (maybe a simple get request).

I can use the following command but it consumes a lot of memory and is not efficient.

```
chromium-browser -app $line
```

Edit: I was able to get the number of websites I can connect too. Combined with this [code](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/peter/wireshark-notes/tree/src/sslkeylog.c) , I dumped the master secrets for the websites which I connected too. This gave me the number of websites I was able to successfully connect too. However, though the file contained 1000 domains, I was able to connect to only 49 sites. (Even after trying a few times)

I cannot figure out why I would connect to only 49 sites (Is it limited by number of child processes that can be created ?) and how to send/recieve application data after connecting to a site.

Comment: Better to use `curl`. In the easiest form, providing it with, say `-XPOST` parameter and some data, you can accomplish what you want. Using s_client is not effective here because you have to type the request all by yourself. Check `man curl`.

Comment: I would eventually like to use the master keys to decrypt the data sent in wireshark. I am not sure if I can dump master keys with the curl -xpost method.

Comment: In the question you are asking "how to connect to some sites and eventually send some data to it". Nothing about dumping keys. You should reformulate the question then. As for the dumping, I'm 90% sure curl uses libssl to make https requests so your trick with LD_PRELOAD should work. Check it with `ldd` though.

Comment: did you check your 50th url in your file ?

Comment: Yes. the url is fine.